# three.js - Reset camera to look at a specific direction in VR

Tags: three.js, webvr

I have a scene with multiple navigation points. When I teleport to any location in VR using my HMD (Oculus rift) the camera remembers the direction it should look at, in the new location and that is logically correct behavior.

But what I want is for camera to point to some other direction(mainly origin).

For this I reset the camera position to (0,0,0) when I teleport to the new location. And it works on desktop but when I use an HMD (Oculus Rift), the camera does not reset to (0,0,0).

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, instead of resetting the camera directly, add the camera to a rig and manipulate that instead. You'll also have to do some math to account for the users's orientation and position relative to their play space.

Here's a working demo:

```js
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const subject = box(1, 1, 1);
subject.position.set(2, 0, 4);
scene.add(subject);

camera.position.y = 1;
const rig = new THREE.Object3D();
rig.add(camera);
scene.add(rig);

const teleportAndLook = (function () {
  const cameraDirection = new THREE.Vector3();
  const teleportToLook = new THREE.Vector3();
  const cameraOffset = new THREE.Vector3();
  return function (teleportPos, lookPos, rig, camera){
    cameraDirection.set(0, 0, -1);
    cameraDirection.applyQuaternion(camera.quaternion);
    cameraDirection.y = 0;
    cameraDirection.normalize();

    teleportToLook.subVectors(lookPos, teleportPos)
    teleportToLook.normalize();
    
    rig.quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(cameraDirection, teleportToLook);
    
    cameraOffset.copy(camera.position);
    cameraOffset.applyQuaternion(rig.quaternion);
    cameraOffset.y = 0;
    rig.position.subVectors(teleportPos, cameraOffset);
  }
})();

function randomTeleport() { 
  const teleportPos = new THREE.Vector3();
  teleportPos.x = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2 * 5;
  teleportPos.z = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2 * 5;
  teleportAndLook(teleportPos, subject.position, rig, camera);
}
randomTeleport();

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.vr.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
document.body.appendChild(WEBVR.createButton(renderer));

function box(w, h, d) {
  const box = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry(w, h, d),
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: new THREE.Color().setHSL(Math.random(), 0.2, 0.2)})
  );
  box.castShadow = true;
  box.receiveShadow = true;
  return box;
}

const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight();
light.position.set(8, 10, 5)
light.castShadow = true;
light.shadow.mapSize.setScalar(2048);
scene.add(light)
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight('white', 0.4));

const floor = box(20, 0.01, 20)
floor.position.y = -0.01;
scene.add(floor);
scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper()); 

renderer.domElement.addEventListener("click", randomTeleport);
setInterval(randomTeleport, 3000)

function animate() {
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
};

renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate);

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; font-size: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.94.0/examples/js/vr/WebVR.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.94.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hi @brianpeiris, I tries this but it does not work. I am using OrbitalControls, could that be a problem?

Comment: Ah, this problem is a bit harder that I first realized. You need to set the dolly's orientation so that it accounts for the camera's current orientation, and you also have to eliminate the vertical components of both orientations. There's some quarternion math involved.

Comment: @brianpeiris Can you elaborate? Got an example?

Comment: Interesting. What about using `lookAt` on the camera? I'm guessing the HMD overrides it, is that the case? (I'm new to VR, pardon me if that's a simple question :)

Comment: Perfect for me! Wish webvr would play nicer with the camera but alas